# How to initialize a shared pointer in the initialization list of a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, shared-ptr

How can I initialize a shared pointer in the initialization list of a constructor?

I have this:

```
Foo::Foo (const callback &cb)
{
    Bar bar;
    bar.m_callback = cb;
    m_ptr = std::make_shared<Bar>(bar);

    //...
}
```

I would like to put this into the initializer list of the contructor.
Something like:

```
Foo::Foo (const callback &cb) :
   m_ptr(std::make_shared<Bar>(?????))
{
  // ...
}
```

Bar is a `struct`:

```
struct Bar
{
  callback_type m_callback;
  // etc.
};
```

Comment: how is `Bar` declared?

Comment: I guess your `Bar` should have a constructor taking the callback.

Comment: I've edited with what Bar is..sorry:)

Comment: If you want `Bar` to be a POD type  then you can use a `{}` braced list of values as initializer. An alternative C++03 way to keep `Bar` as POD type is define a derived class with constructor.

Comment: `std::make_shared<Bar>(bar);` actually calls a (implicitly defined) copy constructor, what is wrong with having a `Bar` instance as a member and call `bar.m_callback = cb;` in the constructor?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a constructor `explicit Bar::Bar(const callback&)`. `explicit` will prevent mistakes related to automatic conversion. Then you can initialize a `shared_ptr<Bar>` like this:

```
Foo::Foo(const callback& cb)
  : m_ptr(std::make_shared<Bar>(cb))
```

See documentation for `make_shared` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Answer (score 4):

Implementing a constructor `Bar::Bar( const callback & )` would be the obvious solution...?!?

```
Foo::Foo( const callback & cb ) :
   m_ptr( std::make_shared<Bar>( cb ) )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry DevSolar.. I forgot to say that Bar was a struct. Question edited

Comment: @waas1919: You *can* write constructors for `struct` too, you know... (At which point, the only difference between `struct` and `class` is the default visibility -- `private` for `class`, `public` for `struct`.) If you *need* to keep `Bar` a POD type, the comments by Alf and Piotr have alternatives.